# Geolocation on the emulator?

Tags: android, geolocation

I develop an application that retrieves the location of the user.

Is that I can test on my emulator (of Eclipse) the geolocation with GPS or other?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect to the emulator using `telnet` and then use the command `geo fix <latitude> <longtitude>` to simulate a change in latitude and longtitude

1. Open a terminal in the `/tools` directory of your SDK's installation
2. Connect to the emulator using `telnet localhost <port number>`. You will get the port number from the emulator window
3. Use `geo fix <x> <y> <z>` to change the location. X and Y are latitude and longtitude in degrees and Z is altitude in meters (it's optional).

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) page has details

Edit: Corrected and added more info

Answer (score 1):

Open DDMS perspective, select an emulator, then put in Location control any coordinates you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, you can set long/lat in the Emulator control view, under 'Location controls'